# Вывести спарсенные данные в другой div при нажатии на option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

Сломал уже всю голову. Есть данные спарсенные с сайта: [user.json](http://demo.sibers.com/users). Суть файла - книга контактов. После того, как файл спарсен, я вывел имена в селект в один див. И вот тут для меня адский геморрой начался. Как, при нажатии на одно из имён, выводить его данные в другой div? Всё тестовое задание встало на этом моменте.. 
script.js:

```
function ajax_get(url, callback) {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        console.log('responseText:' + xmlhttp.responseText);
        try {
            var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err.message + " in " + xmlhttp.responseText);
            return;
        }
        callback(data);
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();}
```

ajax_get('http://demo.sibers.com/users', function(data) {

```
    var output = '<select id="listnames" size="52" onchange="slctt(this, data)"';
    for (var key in data){
      output += '<option>' + data[key].name + '</option>';        
    }
    output += '</select>'
    document.getElementById('fullinfo').innerHTML = output;
```

});

function slctt() {

}

```
<body>
<div id="fullinfo">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script3.js"></script>


</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <h2 id="h">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script3.js"></script>
</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let value;
$(твой div).on('click', (event) => {
     value = event.targer.text();
});
```

Вроде должно работать))

Comment: никакой реакции(

Comment: Стоп, ты хочешь взять инфу о выбраном значении в selectbox?

Comment: Да, открой json. Хочу, что бы при нажатии на имя в селекте, в другой див выпадала вся информация по этому имени.https://ibb.co/jTXE49

Comment: $('select').on('change', function() {
  $(div).text(this.value)
})

Comment: Попробуй задавать в value индекс и потом по нему отлавливать

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то ваше решение выводит в другой див элемент селекта, но проблема в том, что в селекте и находится только имя, других данных там нет. По сути, мне нужно передать в функцию обрабатывающую клик, переменную data, в которой лежат все данные и оттуда уже плясать. Нужно из фукнции, где создается селект и куда попадают данные после парса, взять переменную и засунуть в функцию  с slctt. Я только начал в js и пока кучу вещей не понимаю(

Comment: Ты когда генерируешь теги option можешь задавать value="индекс элемента". Потом, при нажатии на элемент будет так: достаешь value из option и в какую нибудь переменную записываешь data = arr[valueOption]